# pundit returning incorrect values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pundit

I have this Application Policy:

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    @user = user
    @record = record
  end

  ...    

  def create?
    user && user.admin?
  end

  def update?
    create?
  end

  def edit?
    create?
  end
end
```

PostPolicy looks something like this:

```
class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  ...
  def create?
    super || (user && user.in_committee?)
  end
  def update?
    super || (user && user.committees.include?(record.group))
  end
  def edit?
    update?
  end
  ...
end
```

Now when a user that is not admin i.e `user` returns true (it exists) and `user.admin?` returns false (it is not an admin) tries to edit or update a post we check the application policy. We would now expect that when the user tries to edit a post it would get access denied since `update?` returns `super.update?` and `super.update?` returns `super.create?` which should return `false`. (`(user && user.committees.include?(record.group))` returns false)

This is not the case. If we print
`user && user.admin?` inside of ApplicationPolicy's `create?` it prints out false if we then print out `create?` inside `update?` it prints out true. I tried doing a fast check without pundit but that worked as [expected](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/3372e/2)

I have now solved this simply by changing the body of `update?` to:

```
def update?
  user && user.admin?
end
```

Inside ApplicationPolicy which solves my problem. So I guess I'm mostly curious why this would happen and if someone has encountered the same issue.

Comment: You don't need to override the methods. Only declare/override in the PostPolicy the methods specifics of a post.

Comment: May be you have 2 method definition for `update?` in one of the classes? Only guess, because you omit some code. http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/2a1b4/2

Comment: I left out some code since it wasn't relevant to the issue problem which is post-specific but since it creates some confusion I'll edit it in.